# Ensuring Priority for Key Transactions in a Substrate Chain

Tags: substrate-node-template, transactions

I'm currently working on a substrate chain and have implemented a pallet where off-chain workers submit price data of other chains.

My requirement is for these prices to be updated by the workers every 20 seconds. However, I'm concerned about potential network congestion, for instance, if someone floods the system with an enormous volume of transactions.

Could anyone advise on how to prevent such issues? Is there a mechanism to prioritize transactions in the queue, ensuring that specific extrinsics are always processed as a priority by validators ?

I don't want to prioritize by specific account, but by extrinsics !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to consider this prior answer: [Transaction pool extrinsic prioritization](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/transaction-pool-extrinsic-prioritization?rq=1)

If the runtime determines that the transaction is valid it returns a [ValidTransaction](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/transaction_validity/struct.ValidTransaction.html) struct which contains a priority.

Runtime engineers can implement the priority any way they see fit, and a few standards have emerged.

You can find the [TransactionPriority here](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/transaction_validity/type.TransactionPriority.html)