# Is there a way to replace or cancel an extrinsic from the mempool?

Tags: extrinsic, mempool

Just like cancelling and speed up transactions on Ethereum context, is there a mechanism to replace or manipulate extrinsics from the mempool?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this [depends](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3388/2005) on the chain's ordering of extrinsics by their priority. But for default chain with `pallet_transaction_payment`, you can create new extrinsic with the same nonce as the extrinsic you want to cancel and include some `tip`. Since block authors are programmed to maximize their profits, they will [include](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/client/transaction-pool#problem-statement) the transaction with a higher value (fee per unit of weight).

> In the case of FRAME the first property is simply making sure that the fee per weight unit is the highest (high tip values), the second is about avoiding feeding transactions that cannot be part of the next block (they are invalid, obsolete, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There's also an [RPC call](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#removeextrinsicbytesorhash-vecextrinsicorhash-vechash) to remove an extrinsic from the pool.